# How to run 32bit eclipse (ODeV) on 64 Bit Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: java, eclipse, jre

How to run 32bit eclipse (ODeV) on 64 Bit Ubuntu 13.04?

Problem is 64 bit version of ODeV preconfigured eclipse does not exists.... so I have to use 32bit one which doesn’t start on U64 bit.

```
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=1.7.0_25
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_CA
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-10-19 14:13:18.526
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 32-bit SWT libraries on 64-bit JVM
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
```

I have whatever default JRE installed via Ubuntu Software Center.... I assume it is 64bit - OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime

And if I wont figure this out, installation of Ubuntu on my laptop is doomed.... to much hassle with everything... :(

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who has the same question, I found a description [here](http://rachaelandtom.info/node/1485). I did not try the solution myself, but it sounds helpful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.